# How to retrieve users info (and also roles) based on bearer token without web-api?

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity, azure-active-directory

I have custom webservices.
Our front-end application will handle the authentication.
Our middleware-layer will consume requests with the Bearer-token.

The Middleware needs to figure out who the user is by calling the Graph-api presumably.
The middleware is not basic Web-API, but some 3rd party tooling.
All I have is the Token and the httpContext.

How can I validate the Bearer token that it's correct
How can I retrieve the user's info on the Graph Api?

Answer (score 1):

Bearer token should contain all the information you need. Suppose this token is Jwt, You should be able to decode it and see what claims it contain. Have a look at "[System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt)"  nuget package. It contain JwtSecurityTokenHandler class that maybe helpful parsing the token.

Answer (score 0):

Your service layer does not have to be Web API to be able to use the ADAL to get tokens from Azure Active Directory. I think the following articles by Vittorio should help you understand how to interact with AAD to be able to talk to the Graph API:

- http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/22/group-amp-role-claims-use-the-graph-api-to-get-back-isinrole-and-authorize-in-windows-azure-ad-apps/
- http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/29/using-adals-acquiretokenby-authorizationcode-to-call-a-web-api-from-a-web-app/

Answer (score 0):

Good news: we have recently turned on the Application Roles feature in Azure AD, using which an app can declare roles that can be assigned to users and groups in the Azure management portal (roles assignments live in Azure AD). And when the user signs in to the app, Azure AD includes a roles claim in the bearer token (token for the middleware service in your case)

Read about it here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles.aspx

Deep dive post and video on app roles feature is here: http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/

Hope that helps.